# I have removed the duplicates by using append but does not no exactly how it worked

Tags: python

I used this code to remove duplicate data in **numbers** list, but I am unsure exactly; how it worked because I am a beginner in programming.

```
numbers=[1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 4, 7, 8, 7]
uniques=[]
for number in numbers:
    if number not in uniques:
        uniques.append(number)
print(uniques)
```

Comment: Python makes code that practically works as read. You are making a new list, uniques, appending to this new list only if the number is not in the new list already. And you are doing this for every number in the original list, hence you are “removing” duplicates. Note the original numbers list is unaffected by this code.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to read the comment mentioned in with the code. It may help you to understand.

```
# input given by the user as below
numbers=[1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 4, 7, 8, 7,9,1] 
# create blank array which store the result
uniques=[] 
# execute the for loop for input array
for number in numbers: 
    # individual array element is given as input. Ex. 1 is given as input
    # Check that number is present in the unique array. 
    if number not in uniques: 
        #If not than appned to the result array
        uniques.append(number) 
#print the result array
print(uniques)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
numbers = [1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 4, 7, 8, 7]
uniques = []
for number in numbers:
    if number not in uniques:
        uniques.append(number)
        print(uniques)
```

Your code removes duplicates in your starting list by iterating through all the items in the list, checks if it is in your `uniques` list, and if not, appends to it.

Let's try to break it down. If you were to put a print statement here, you can see how it iterates:

```
numbers = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3]
uniques = []
for number in numbers:
    print(number)
```

```
1
1
2
3
3
```

For the first iteration, for example, we check if `1` doesn't exist in your `uniques` list with `if number not in uniques:`. Since it starts empty, it is not. That if condition is met, and it appends to your list. Then on the second iteration, when `1` comes up again, we do the same check to see if it's not in `uniques`. Since the list is `[1]`, that returns `False`, and that `append` statement is skipped. This continues until all values in `numbers` have been iterated through.

A simpler example to remove duplicates can be seen as:

```
numbers = list(set([1, 1, 2, 3, 3]))
print(numbers)
```

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

This works because the `set` type in Python only allows for 1 instance of every value. Then we set it back to a list, essentially doing the same operation as your code above. The only downside you have to be aware of is that the `set` type does not allow for order, so it's possible to lose the original order of your input list.

Comment: Thanks @Shane Smiskol mate. Really appreciate it.